# Invoke custom service in D365 F&O using postman

Tags: http, request, postman, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to call my custom service which I have developed in D365 F&O through postman. I am able to invoke the method however I need to pass data to the method as well can anyone please help me regarding where do I need to provide this argument value in postman. Also I need to check the reply data, how can I process this.

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test). Step 14. contains a parameter example. Step 17. shows where to find the reply data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is specific to OData call could you please help me understand how do I invoke a function having parameters in a custom service

Comment: Do you need to use Postman to test the custom service? The documentation describes how you can use SoapUI to test a custom service.

Comment: As @FH-Inway described you can test the custom service by using Soap UI, it is the best way. if you want to test Odata service like DatEntity use post man. in both of the ways you can pass what ever the parameters you want. If you still need help with postman i can help you out